# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object-same codes work for some firms but not others

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following codes:

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
  

master_data=[{'cik_number': '1556179', 'company_name': 'RMR Industrials, Inc.', 'form_id': '10-K', 'date': '20200103', 'file_url': 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1556179/0001104659-20-000861.txt'}]

sentence_regex = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z](?:[^\.!?]|\.\d)*[\.!?]")

def identify_sentences(input_text:str):
    """Returns all sentences in the input text"""
    sentences = re.findall(sentence_regex, input_text)
    return sentences 

rdterms=['research and development','R&D','product development','research, development',
          'research, engineering, and development','research and product development']

# creates a list of earnings regex expressions 
rdterms_regex=[re.compile(r'\b' + term + r'\b', re.IGNORECASE) 
                    for term in rdterms] 

def rdsentence(sentence:str):
    """Checks whether a sentence is R&D-oriented."""
    for term in rdterms_regex:    
        if term.search(sentence): 
            return True 
    return False

for entry in master_data: 
    path=entry['file_url']
    r=requests.get(path, headers={"User-Agent": "b2g"})
    content=r.content.decode('utf8')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")
    soup=str(soup)
    entry['count']=0
    sentences=identify_sentences(soup)
    for sentence in sentences:
        if rdsentence(sentence) is True:
            entry['count']=entry['count']+1
        else:
            continue

print(master_data)
len(master_data)
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

If I change the master_data line to

```
master_data=[{'cik_number': '1041588', 'company_name': 'ACCESS-POWER INC', 'form_id': '10-K', 'date': '20200102', 'file_url': 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1041588/0001041588-20-000001.txt'}]
```

everything works well.
Why do the codes work for some firms but not others? How should I modify the codes? Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text, it can't be searched easily.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! If I just copy and paste the error message, will it be readable, since the color and indent will lose?

Comment: Hey Julie! You can preserve the formatting, but indeed, the colours will be lost. I think they are not that important though. Preferably, run the code from the commandline as well, since that removes one more possible influence on the problem. Glad you found an answer nonetheless, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that str(soup) is not well-defined, and throws html5lib into an endless loop.
The correct is

```
soup = soup.text
```